# Trouble After Update, Removing Plugin

Tags: plugins, css, ajax, updates

I'm editing this site http://www.millermusicproductions.com/ currently and I updated WP 3.0.1 to 3.3.1. After updating, the page now is zoomed in compared to how it had been and I have no idea why. Here's another site with the same template that is sort of zoomed out in comparison. I want it to end up looking like this. http://www.millermusiclessons.com/

Also, I am trying to get rid of the login in the upper-right corner. I go to plugins and deactivate a plugin called "Login with AJAX", then I refresh the page and only the page's header displays. Please help me get rid of the login. I posted several threads on the WP Support Forums and received no answers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the the page is not "zoomed" in.

It appears that the image:
http://www.millermusicllc.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/DSC_3508.jpg

Is bigger on the first link as apposed to the second link, also styling on the style.css is different in general:

First link:

```
<img src="http://www.millermusicllc.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/DSC_3508.jpg" alt="" title="miller" width="320" height="330" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-30">
```

Second link:

```
<img src="http://www.millermusicllc.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/DSC_3508.jpg" alt="" title="miller" width="320" height="330" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-30">
```

These SHOULD be the same size...

But on the second link you have this in your style.css

```
#sidebar_img img {
    width: 250px !important;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

The first link doesn't have this in its style.css

As well as other styling that makes the font size bigger.

So that's that problem...

---

My guess as to why the login thing isn't going away is that either the plugin didn't really de-activate OR it's embedded in your theme.

If I understand things correctly here...when you delete the plugin..your site only loads the header.

This probably means that you have code that depends on that plugin...which is probably either in another plugin OR it's in the theme.

The reason you only see the header is because it's throwing a fatal error.

Comment: I don't think it's embedded in the theme because the lessons site doesn't have it. If it was wouldn't it appear on the lessons site? How can I tell...I'm not very good with WordPress.

Comment: Have you deleted the plugin? Try that. Also - is there a widget that has that code in it? Also - it could be embeded in the theme because we just proved that the sites are different in terms of the style.css which means the themes have diverged.

Comment: I just deleted the plugin. How only the header loads, the same thing that happens when it is deactivated. How can I check if it's hardcoded into the theme? I know the name of the theme is flooky. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I just reinstalled login with ajax for the time being so the page loads fully.

Comment: If I understand things correctly here...when you delete the plugin..your site only loads the header.

This probably means that you have code that depends on that plugin...which is probably either in another plugin OR it's in the theme.

The reason you only see the header is because it's throwing a fatal error.

Comment: Any idea on how I can find that piece of code? I'm going to work on deactivating the other plugins and I'll see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Check your servers error logs. Or turn on error reporting. I don't know your servers setup, so at this juncture you may need to call your hosting provider and ask them for help.

Answer (score 0):

So I can't honestly see a difference in terms of zoom between both sites but in relation to the login area if its not a plugin then its probably set in the menu. In the WordPress backend, look under apperance and then menus. If that doesn't work, check to see if this theme has any special widgets that could be set under the header in the widget section.

Comment: The pages don't look different to you? There's a huge difference for me when I pull them up side-by-side. Also, the login area is a plugin. That's why I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your site, I see two huge issues first:

- Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [action$=wp-comments-post.php]
- ReferenceError: Shadowbox is not defined

The first is likely due to a comment management plugin you have enabled on your site that isn't compatible with the new version of jQuery bundled with WP 3.3+.

The second is likely also being caused by a plugin.  Your site is attempting to load a Shadowbox plugin that likely conflicts with the new version of jQuery as well.

Standard practice when you have a broken site after upgrading is to:

- Disable all plugins
- Enable plugins 1 and a time until things break so you can identify what's going wrong.

It looks like we've already identified what's breaking ... so find which plugins are causing this, disable them, and see if that fixes things.

Comment: I disabled all of the plugins and the page loads the same as it does when only the Login with Ajax is disabled-header only. So I assume this means all of my other plugins are fine...

Comment: In that case I second what others have said. There's some dependency in your theme's header file on the Login with Ajax plugin.